# How can I find how many times a string in a list is a substring of another string that is in another list?

Tags: list

Basically I have to lists of strings

```
list_one = ["a", "b", "c"]
list_two = ["arrr", "aaa", "acacb"]
```

expected output would be 9, since "a", "b" and "c" appear 9 times.
Sorry for my English!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What have you tried? What language are you working with?

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please tell us what language are you using, and what have you tried as a solution?

Now since you called it a list, I am assuming it to be python

```
counter = []
for s in list_one:
    temp = list(map(lambda x: x.count(s), list_two))
    counter.append(sum(temp))

output = sum(counter)
```

If it is not python, try to understand the logic and apply it in the language you are using